# Handling an HTML button click event in C++ code

Tags: javascript, c++, html, windows, mfc

I have a Windows native C++/Win32/MFC dialog app.  I'm using the IE ActiveX control in the dialog to render some HTML content.  The HTML being rendered contains a button.  The button has an onClick javascript handler as shown below.

```
<input type="button" id="uniqueButtonID" name="uniqueButtonName" value="blue" onClick="OnButtonClick('blue');">
```

Currently the button click is handled in the page by the javascript handler shown.  This all works.

I'd like to, instead, handle the button click in the dialog C++ code.

I have some experience handling other events in the dialog.  For example, the below works and allows handling the doc complete event and navigation.

```
BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(DMyDlg, CDialog)
ON_EVENT(DMyDlg, IDC_EXPLORER2, 259, DMyDlg::DocumentCompleteExplorer2, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT)
ON_EVENT(DMyDlg, IDC_EXPLORER2, 250, DMyDlg::BeforeNavigate2, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PBOOL)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()
```

These are pre-defined well known events though.  Not sure how to translate that into handling something I've defined in the button in the onClick="" section.

Anyone know how to do this?  The motivation here is that I have some code used in another C++ app which defines some business logic.  I want the same business logic used here.  Currently I have to translate that into Javascript every time.  If I could handle the event in the C++ code I could just copy/paste (or re-use through a DLL) and avoid the Javascript translation stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a COM object as the bridge between JavaScript and C++.  The JavaScript initialization code will look something like:

```
var myhelper = new ActiveXObject("MyCompany.MyHelper");
```

Note that despite the name "ActiveXObject", the object does not have to be a full ActiveX control, just a COM object.  Then in your onClick handler you can just do:

```
myhelper.DoThis();
myhelper.DoThat();
```

The "fun" part is creating the COM object in C++ - IDL files, ATL classes, IDispatch, IUnknown and all that stuff I am trying to forget.

One thing though - if the C++ code exists in your application exe (not in a separate COM DLL), don't forget that when your program starts up, you must create a class factory instance for "MyCompany.MyHelper" and register it with COM so that the "new ActiveXObject" in JavaScript succeeds.

[update 1]

I should have added in my initial response - I don't actually recommend doing this if you can avoid it.  Back before C# and .NET existed, we in our company actually though COM was a good thing and it was worth the time and effort to learn it.  Today ... not so much.

In your case, having your business logic in C++ and again in JavaScript might seem like a lot of extra work - but at least it is extra work that you can plan, allocate resources to and have a hope of being able to finish.  Once you go down the path of C++/COM/ActiveScripting, when stuff stops working - there is no limit to the amount of time you might spend trying to chase down obscure COM related issues.  Anyhow good luck!

Comment: I did do a lot of reading on OLE/COM back in the day but have tried to forget it :)  I'm getting a headache now trying to sort through the quickest/easiest way to stand up a simple object just to get a method call from the Javascript...

Comment: I hear you; thats how it currently is and is working.  The C++ business logic is just translated into Javascript.  As a side note, I did think of a really hacky way to do this -- almost ashamed to say it, but...  I am able to get/set the value of checkboxes in the HTML from C++ pretty easily (by just accessing the document object, etc.).  So perhaps one possibility would be to have a hidden checkbox.  When you click the button the onClick just sets the checkbox.  The C++ code polls and if the checkbox is set, clears it and then does its thing.  Yes, I know, horrible hacky :)

Comment: I posted a followon question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645985/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-simple-com-object-in-vs2010-using-native-c) to see if anyone has some tips on easily standing up a COM object.  Even beyond this specific application (where the possible solution is to just leave the logic in Javascript) being able to have a better integration between the C++ and HTML/javascript would be nice for other projects.