# What is the easiest way to create a simple COM object in VS2010 using native/C++ code?

Tags: c++, windows, com

This is a followon to a prior question I posted (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463113/handling-an-html-button-click-event-in-c-code)).  I'm trying to call my native/C++ code from Javascript running in an HTML page.  The answer in the referenced question was to create a COM object.  The Javascript can then create an instance of the COM object and invoke methods on it getting to the native/C++ code.

So now I'm left with trying to create a simple COM object to accept the call from the Javascript.  It looks like the way to go is to create a DLL and put the COM object in that DLL.  Years ago I did tons of reading on COM and have tried to forget it since then :)  Now I'm getting a headache wondering how to go about this easily without becoming an expert in COM.

Is there a simple/easy way to setup a DLL with a COM object that you would recommend?

EDIT: My application is written using native C++/Win32/MFC.  I have an MFC dialog which uses the IE ActiveX browser control to render locally generated HTML.  Currently the button handler code is all in Javascript, but as you can see from the referenced question, my goal is to handle it on the C++ side.

Comment: Sounds like you would have been much better off with Google's V8.

Comment: The COM object accessed from javascript needs to implement specific interfaces for security and other features. Unfortunately I don't have those interfaces handy but I'm sure someone will point you to the right ones.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Not sure that would help me.  I have an MFC dialog which uses the IE ActiveX browser control to render the HTML which contains the Javascript.  Don't know how I'd plug V8 into that equation.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious its all client side, the HTML with the Javascript is rendered in the IE ActiveX browser control running in an MFC dialog app.  Are you saying I can't have a COM object with a single method void foo(); invoked by the Javascript?  Not worried about security interfaces unless they're absolutely required here.

Comment: @Nerdtron Correct. In order to use a COM object in Internet Explorer that is accessible from scripts you MUST implement the additional security interfaces. This is a requirement of IE not COM.

Comment: @Nerdtron One of the interfaces that must be implemented is IObjectSafety. IIRC there is one other interface that needs to be implemented but I could be wrong.

Comment: This may not be helpful for your situation but if you develop your app in Qt, you can integrate your C++ objects into their embeddable webkit view in a few lines of code and no need for COM

Comment: @cppguy no that wouldn't help here.  The app is written using MFC not Qt.

Comment: @Nerdtron If this is a personal project I'd highly recommend looking into Qt. If it's work related, I'd recommend discussing with your managers eventually moving to Qt as it's significantly easier to develop with than MFC (I've done both professionally) AND it's cross platform and allows for many modern UI paradigms that are an enormous hassle in MFC

Comment: @cppguy I've looked into Qt and it looks very nice.  Definitely would be a good option for a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know the easy and fast way to create COM objects is to create an ATL project.
here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38254/A-Beginner-Tutorial-for-Writing-Simple-COM-ATL-DLL) that explains the steps to follow.

Comment: That article doesn't cover creating your object with a class factory.  I think you need to supply a class factory in order to be able to create the object.  Looks like ATL supports this, just not sure how to add that in.  Any suggestions?